# Do I need to register my Entity Listener? Where do I put it in the project?

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

I'm trying to create an entity listener to my entity like described in

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners

The reference I found in the Symfony docs is

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#creating-the-listener-class

which has a note talking about entity listeners.

If I put my FooListener in the same folder as the Foo entity (AppBundle\Entity in this case) and make the annotation `@EventListener`, the listener works. But I don't want to leave the listeners in the Entity folder, and I don't want to create extra configuration by registering the listener as a service if I don't need to. What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try use full path to FooListener f.e.
@ORM\EntityListeners({"AppBundle\EventListener\FooListener"})